# How to set a global property on the string constructor in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I want to define a property on the string constructor, and I want then to access this property from any file in my project. for example:

file1.js

```
String.capitalize = function(){
this.//...etc
}
```

file2.js

```
"Hello nice to meet you".capitalize()
```

Comment: you need to specify extension on prototype. Something like: String.prototype.capitalize = function(){ ... };

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42702634 But please don't mutate built-in prototypes

Comment: String.prototype.capitalize is a bad practice or not?

Comment: Very bad practice. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a new String prototype function like in the example below

```js
String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
 return this.toUpperCase();
};




console.log("Hello nice to meet you".capitalize());
```

Comment: Why doesn't show code completion? and: do you think this is a bad practice?

Comment: I can really recommend reading the first answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice